# Trying to precompile my MVC ASP.NET application, keep getting strange Namespace assembly reference error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC3, Razor, C#, .NET4,EF4.1

I am trying to precompile my MVC web application using the "publishing" tool, setting the precompile option to non updateable, and not merging the output dlls.

The error I get is :

```
Error   49  The type or namespace name 'vmSection' does not exist in the namespace 'MyApp.MVC3' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\4ce30959\16e34b5\App_Web_index.cshtml.43461f6f.0.cs  36  0   SmartS.MVC3.ED
```

I did a solution wide search for "vmSection" and it returned 0 results. I deleted everything in the "4ce30959" folder, and still no solution. I cleaned and rebuilt the project. I cleaned and rebuilt the solution and still no resolution.

Interestingly I cannot even find, not even on my entire hard drive, the file in question:

```
App_Web_index.cshtml.43461f6f.0.cs
```

Very puzzled as "vmSection" does not exist in solution source.

Comment: Rebuild the project, but save the generated `cshtml.*.cs` file and paste the indicated line (and surrounding code) here.

Comment: Thanks for this. Sorry I am not quite understanding you. When I rebuild the project where should I look for the cshtml.*.cs file. Incidentally I could not find "App_Web_index.cshtml.43461f6f.0.cs "

Comment: The path to the `cshtml.*.cs` file is specified in the error message, it's located under `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.xxx\Temporary ASP.NET Files`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this. Trouble is I can find the file in this location. Will try again later. Thanks for your help thus far.

Comment: Make sure you have "Show all files" enabled and uncheck "Hide protected operating system files" in Folder Options.

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes tried this. Still no joy. I just get ".dlls" and ".compiled" files in the Tempory ASP.NET File/root/xxx/xxx folder. Will soldier on. I also discovered that I was getting some unhelpful files in obj/release which is producing some errors so trying to clear these up now which may end up sorting the root/xxx/xxx/ folder issue.

Comment: Now Sorted. Many thanks.

Comment: If you create an answer then I can mark it as such. Thanks

Comment: I don't know what you did to fix it :)

Comment: I ended up looking in the compilemerge folder within obj/ to find the culprits. Basically I had quite a few old files which I had excluded. However they were still mysteriously appearing in compilemerge with missing assemblies since they were old code. In the end I cleaned up and deleted all excluded files and finally the project published with precompiled views. Thanks for your support.